# Am I able to write a chrome extension that can grab a registration cookie from another website and set it with that same value on the current page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I started writing some code for this and have ran into this exception in the console:

```
"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
```

I came here to ask if I should continue trying or if this is even possible. I am aware that you can also use an iFrame but from looking at other posts you cant pull cookies out of the site an iFrame points to.

The only JS ive written thus far for the extension:

```
(function loadXMLDoc() {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 || xmlhttp.status == 200) {
  console.log(xmlhttp.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie'));

  var response = xmlhttp.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie');

}
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://www.cars.com/profile/global/user-summary/", 
true);
xmlhttp.send();
})()
```

Comment: I think it's possible if you inject a content script into the iframe and use messaging.

Comment: You can't configure the other server, I guess ? Could you configure a reverse proxy to the other site on your Server ?

Comment: @wOxxOm could you explain further or maybe link a page that explains that method? i have noticed your comments on other such iframe related posts. if youve explained this already please link that up here.

Comment: @heug, that would require some time to make because I don't see an existing example. I'll do it later if it's still needed at that point.

Comment: For your `XMLHttpRequest` to work you just need to add `https://www.cars.com/` to your manifest `permissions` https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

Comment: @rsanchez i have my permissions currently as   "permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "history",
    "<all_urls>"
  ] ....is the last one a non-functional expression?

Comment: @wOxxOm if you get around to that and can follow up i would be quite grateful, i will keep banging away intermittently while im at work haha.

Comment: @wOxxOm ...any chance you could point me in the right direction here? getting kind of muddled between tactics as ive seen web results pointing to sandboxing, using iframes or not using iframes, etc etc